# Substitute for "The thought came to my mind"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I want a substitute for the sentence "The thought **came to my mind**". It should be a slightly formal substitute as I am writing a formal letter. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_to_mind, http://thesaurus.com/browse/come+to+mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a *good* thought, you could use *inspired*.

> I was inspired to...

Answer (score 7):

[**oc·cur**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occur) intransitive verb \ə-ˈkər\ (merriam-webster)

3 : to come to mind
"*an idea that has occurred to me*"